# flash player is outside of div (only in IE)

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash, fusioncharts

I'm using the following code to display a fusionchart inside a div tag.  The chart is rendered correctly in Chrome and FF, but with IE it's outside the boundaries of my div tag.  Any idea what I'm missing?

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: auto;border: solid 1px #ff0000;><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" id="chart" >
<param name="movie" value="../FusionCharts/Column2D.swf" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px">
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<embed src="../FusionCharts/Column2D.swf" flashVars="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px" quality="high" width="100%" height="500px" name="chart" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
</object></div>
```

IE always seems to be difficult...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing `/`

Try changing

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px">
```

to

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px"/>
```

Comment: the div shows the correct size but the chart is only a fraction of the parent div now...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of unclosed elements and missing qoutes. You need to change,

```
 <param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px">
```

To this...

```
 <param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=' . 'chart_data/'.$xml_file . '&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500px">
```

And this...

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: auto;border: solid 1px #ff0000;>
```

To this...

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: auto;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
```

This should solve your problem.

Happy coding bud.

Comment: I've made the changes but now I think it has to do with the order in which this gets displayed. This div tag is inside a set of jquery tabs so maybe this should be called after the tabs load ?

Comment: Yes it should, it can't get it's width or position if it has nothing to relate to. Once the tabs are loaded it will have a reference point as to where it will be placed and how it should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try setting Flash vars in this fashion?

`&chartWidth=100%&chartHeight=500` (without the px)

Also,

You can try mentioning :

`<object width="100%" ..>`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close quote at the end of the `<div>`'s style attribute.

Maybe try adding `overflow:hidden` if it helps.